# What's Thymeleaf "prefix" relative to?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm just starting using Thymeleaf and I'm trying to understand the `setPrefix()` method in the template resolver. There are cases that I understand, like `setPrefix("classpath:/com/package")` or `setPrefix("file:folder")`  (relative to working directory).

But I still don't understand what, for example, `setPrefix("/views/")` refers to. Where Thymeleaf expects the `views` folder to be? Does the `/` at the beginning means that is an absolute path? If so, where's the 'root'?

Does it depends of the specific TemplateResolver? In my instance, I'm using the SpringResourceTemplateResolver.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SpringResourceTemplateResolver, the prefix is relative to the root of the war file (or the web-app base directory when unpacked).

When using Maven as build system, the source folder for this is `src/main/webapp`. For example, if you `setPrefix("/views/")` your templates should be put in `src/main/webapp/views/`.

Hint: Use WEB-INF directory to protect from end-users retrieving the templates directly.